# Can't add script in Unity engine

Tags: c#

I have a problem in Unity. In this case, I prepared a code and tried to associate it with an object, however, the image message that I am going to attach came up. The problem is that this error is related to the file name, for example, the file has the name "OptionMenuControler", it should have the class with that name in the file, right at the beginning. At first the class is with the name of the file. I previously troubleshoot this problem, but it happened again for no reason that I understand. It could be an error in the codes, but there are some files that were associated correctly and when I went to associate them again to see if it was just this file "OptionMenuControler" that was in trouble, the other files presented the same error, even those that had already been associated. What can it be?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bEF0.png)

I tried putting the file name in the class that asked for it. I also checked the code for problems, but nothing worked.

Comment: Controler should be spelled as Contro**ll**er, are you sure the file name and the class name are same?